# Cordova: App close event handler (Android)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need an event handler for the event that my app will be destroyed by the user. For example the user goes to the list of opened apps and closes my app by swiping.
The event is necessary for me because my app plays an audiobook and I want to stop the book when my app is closed. Otherwise the audiobook still plays for round about half a minute.

Is there an event handler for this?

Info:

- I'm using Ionic and Angular as well.
- The audiobook should run in background mode but no when the app is closed

**EDIT:**

I don't need an uninstall event. I just want to know when my app is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect uninstall event in phonegap app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317635/detect-uninstall-event-in-phonegap-app)